# porto theme css is not loading on frontend in magento 2.0.4

Tags: magento-2.0.4

Installation is successfully completed but my css is not loading only html is displaying on frontend.
I am getting following error no css is loaded I have run deploy command also

```
GET rootdirectory/magento204/pub/static/frontend/Smartwave/porto/en_US/mage/calendar.css 
(index):18 GET rootdirectory/magento204/pub/static/frontend/Smartwave/porto/en_US/css/styles-m.css 
(index):20 GET rootdirectory/magento204/pub/static/frontend/Smartwave/porto/en_US/bootstrap/css/bootstrap-theme.css 
(index):21 GET rootdirectory/magento204/pub/static/frontend/Smartwave/porto/en_US/owl.carousel/assets/owl.carousel.css 
(index):19 GET rootdirectory/magento204/pub/static/frontend/Smartwave/porto/en_US/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.css 
(index):22 GET rootdirectory/magento204/pub/static/frontend/Smartwave/porto/en_US/css/animate.css 
(index):23 GET rootdirectory/magento204/pub/static/frontend/Smartwave/porto/en_US/icon-fonts/css/porto-icons-codes.css 
(index):24 GET rootdirectory/magento204/pub/static/frontend/Smartwave/porto/en_US/icon-fonts/css/animation.css 
(index):25 GET rootdirectory/magento204/pub/static/frontend/Smartwave/porto/en_US/css/custom.css 
(index):26 GET rootdirectory/magento204/pub/static/frontend/Smartwave/porto/en_US/Smartwave_Filterproducts/css/filterproducts.css 
(index):27 GET rootdirectory/magento204/pub/static/frontend/Smartwave/porto/en_US/css/styles-l.css 
(index):31 GET rootdirectory/magento204/pub/static/frontend/Smartwave/porto/en_US/requirejs/require.js 
(index):32 GET rootdirectory/magento204/pub/static/frontend/Smartwave/porto/en_US/mage/requirejs/mixins.js 
requirejs-config.js:58 Uncaught TypeError: require is not a function(anonymous function) @ requirejs-config.js:58(anonymous function) @ requirejs-config.js:63(anonymous function) @ requirejs-config.js:601
(index):34 GET rootdirectory/magento204/pub/static/frontend/Smartwave/porto/en_US/jquery.js 
(index):183 GET rootdirectory/magento204/pub/static/frontend/Smartwave/porto/en_US/images/logo.svg 404 (Not Found)
(index):35 GET rootdirectory/magento204/pub/static/frontend/Smartwave/porto/en_US/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js 
(index):37 GET rootdirectory/magento204/pub/static/frontend/Smartwave/porto/en_US/mage/calendar.css 
(index):43 Uncaught TypeError: require is not a function(anonymous function) @ (index):43
(index):51 Uncaught TypeError: require.config is not a function(anonymous function) @ (index):51
(index):292 Uncaught TypeError: require is not a function(anonymous function) @ (index):292
(index):357 Uncaught TypeError: require is not a function(anonymous function) @ (index):357
(index):427 Uncaught TypeError: require is not a function(anonymous function) @ (index):427
(index):962 Uncaught TypeError: require is not a function(anonymous function) @ (index):962
(index):1054 Uncaught TypeError: require is not a function(anonymous function) @ (index):1054
(index):1135 Uncaught TypeError: require is not a function(anonymous function) @ (index):1135
(index):1215 Uncaught TypeError: require is not a function(anonymous function) @ (index):1215
(index):473 GET rootdirectory/magento204/pub/static/frontend/Smartwave/porto/en_US/Magento_Catalog/images/product/placeholder/small_image.jpg 404 (Not Found)
(index):28 GET rootdirectory/magento204/pub/static/frontend/Smartwave/porto/en_US/css/print.css 
(index):474 GET rootdirectory/magento204/pub/static/frontend/Smartwave/porto/en_US/Magento_Catalog/images/product/placeholder/thumbnail.jpg 404 (Not Found)
logo.svg:1 GET rootdirectory/magento204/pub/static/frontend/Smartwave/porto/en_US/images/logo.svg 404 (Not Found)
```

Comment: I also face same problem